# Symfony2 FOSFacebookBundle use:

Tags: facebook, symfony, integration, bundle

I have try a lot to integrate FOSFacebookBundle in my application, but can't get configure it. May be the gitHub instruction is a bit confusion or something else anyhow:

Where to study and know easily integration of FOSFacebookBundle in symfony 2.0 for the facility of login from facebook..

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension::addSecurityListenerFactory() in D:.....\projectName\vendor\bundles\FOS\FacebookBundle\FOSFacebookBundle.php on line 25**

Comment: This is too vague.  What errors are you seeing? What's your configuration look like? etc

Comment: @richsage, i say i didn't understand how to configure it to symfony2...i try its manual but don't know how to configure it for login from facebook.

Comment: again, StackOverflow can't help if people can't see what you've tried and what may be missing. Please post eg your `security.yml` so that people can see.

Comment: i actually not understanding the steps of installing FOSFacebookBundle  to symfony2, because the steps are a bit confusion for me..... can you know the easy steps of getting basic of integration of that bundle....Thanks.

Comment: @richsage : i edited the question, and it give me that fatal error:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `master` branch of the FOSFacebookBundle tracks the `master` branch of Symfony, which is currently for the 2.1 release.  Since you're using Symfony 2.0, you need to use the `2.0` branch of the bundle. In your `deps` file, adjust the version line as follows:

```
[FOSFacebookBundle]
    git=git://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle.git
    target=/bundles/FOS/FacebookBundle
    version=origin/2.0
```

See the 2.0 branch's README for more details on the [repository](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSFacebookBundle/tree/2.0) - follow the detailed installation steps given here.

Comment: Now i have installed it and the login button is displayed, but i how to get the user information or how to do some operation on user data...thanks.